# new adminhtml theme does not show in deploy list

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, phtml, composer

Using Magento 2.1.1, I would like to deploy a new adminhtml theme in cli.
`magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Tc/theme`. 
Result:
`[InvalidArgumentException]
  Tc/theme argument has invalid value, available themes are: Magento/blank, M
  agento/luma, Magento/backend, Venustheme/need`

I follow this link to craete my theme [Create a new storefront theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html). After `magento setup:upgrade`, Tc/theme is added to database `theme` and parent_id is pointing to `Magento/backend`
Here are my codes

`composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.5",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

`registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Tc/theme',
    __DIR__
);
```

`theme.xml`

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento 2 - backend</title>
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> 
 </theme>
```

What I want to do is to custom the phtml in adminhtml. Please help. Thanks.